# Bevel modifier with weights affecting undesired parts

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I'm using the Bevel Modiffier with weight limit method. The problem comes with unweighted parts being affected

Without modifier:

[image: Without modifier]

With modifier

[image: With Bevel modifier]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share this part of your object?

Comment: There it goes https://file.io/lP7EYdNIzVBm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your *Bevel* modifier, it's because you've assigned *Edge Crease* to this edge loop, it prevents the *Subdivision Surface* effect, but as you now have 90° angle between your faces it creates a bad shading:

[image]

To fix it you can enable the *Auto Smooth* option:

[image]